# How to create an Update button for a database?

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem concerning my Update button, I don't know where to start to make it update my SQL database, I use SSMS Microsoft to create my table Subjects and I also connected it with my VS 2010 ULTIMATE where I drag my table to LINQtoSQL and DATASET, I have created a Save button which successfully saves to my database and refreshes my datagridview.

```
[ Private Sub Button18_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    If txtSubjectName.Text = "" Then
        ErrorProvider1.SetError(txtSubjectName, "Subject Name Cannot be Empty!")
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf txtSubSName.Text = "" Then
        ErrorProvider2.SetError(txtSubSName, "Subject Short Name Cannot be Empty!")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim db As New EMSDataContext
    Dim SaveSubject = From C In db.Subjects
            Where C.SubjectName = txtSubjectName.Text
            Select C

    If SaveSubject.Count <> 0 Then
        MsgBox("Subject already exits!!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Alart!!")
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Dim SaveNSubject As New Subject With {.SubjectName = txtSubjectName.Text, .ShortName = txtSubSName.Text}
        db.Subjects.InsertOnSubmit(SaveNSubject)
        db.SubmitChanges()
        MsgBox("Subject added successfully!", MsgBoxStyle.Information + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Information")
    End If
    Registration_Load(sender, e)
    txtSubjectName.Text = ""
    txtSubSName.Text = ""
End Sub]
```

And I also have a Delete button which successfully deletes my data from database and refreshes my datagridview.

```
  [Private Sub Button13_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
    Dim A As New EMSDataContext
    Dim B = From C In A.Subjects
            Where C.ID = Val(DtgvSubject.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value)
            Select C
    Try
        A.Subjects.DeleteOnSubmit(B.FirstOrDefault)
        If MsgBox("Are You Sure to Delete This Record?", MsgBoxStyle.Question + vbYesNo, "Question") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            A.SubmitChanges()
            MsgBox("Record Deleted Successfully!", MsgBoxStyle.Information + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Information")
            txtSubjectName.Text = ""
            txtSubSName.Text = ""
            Registration_Load(sender, e)
        Else
            txtSubjectName.Text = ""
            txtSubSName.Text = ""
            Registration_Load(sender, e)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Select a Record First!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "ALERT!!!")
    End Try
    If B.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Please select list to delete!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Alart!!")

    End If

End Sub]
```

I also created a double click Events of the datagridview cell where I get cells values to my Subject Name textbox and Subject Short Name textbox if I double clicked which is also successfull.

```
 [ Private Sub DtgvSubject_CellDoubleClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DtgvSubject.CellDoubleClick
    Try
        Dim i As Integer
        i = DtgvSubject.CurrentRow.Index
        Me.txtSubjectName.Text = DtgvSubject.Item(1, i).Value
        Me.txtSubSName.Text = DtgvSubject.Item(2, i).Value
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("No Values in the Cells!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Alert!!!")
        Button17_Click(sender, e)
    End Try
End Sub]
```

My Question is, how can I create an Update button to my Database after getting the Values to the Textboxes and update them, Submit Changes and refresh my datagridview?

Comment: Please answer me, i hope my post is understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your inputs are not bound to the dataset, you just need to retrieve the existing record from the database, update the record and save it again.  Something like this should work:

```
public Function updaterecord (field1 as integer, field2 as text) as Object
 Dim db As New EMSDataContext
Dim SaveSubject = From C In db.Subjects
        Where C.SubjectName = txtSubjectName.Text
        Select C
if SaveSubject is not Nothing then
   C.id = field1
   C.name = field2 'etc etc
End if
db.SaveChanges()
return 
From C In db.Subjects
        Where C.SubjectName = txtSubjectName.Text
        Select C
    End Function
```

Comment: Thank you Haim i will try it

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Haim i have solved the Problem using LinqtoSQL

```
 [ Private Sub bnUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles bnUpdate.Click
    If txtClassTeacher.Text = "" Or txtClassName.Text = "" Or txtClassSName.Text = "" Or cboClassSection.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Select the data you want Update Please!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "ALERT!!!")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim db As New EMSDataContext
    Dim SaveClasses = From c In db.Classtbls
                      Where c.ID = Val(DtgvClasstbl.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value)
                      Select c

    For Each c As Classtbl In SaveClasses
        c.Class_Teacher = txtClassTeacher.Text
        c.Class_Name = txtClassName.Text
        c.Short_Name = txtClassSName.Text
        c.Section = cboClassSection.Text
        'Inserting additional changes
    Next
    'Submitting changes to the Database
    Try
        If MsgBox("Are You Sure You Want Update This Record?", MsgBoxStyle.Question + vbYesNo, "Question") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            db.SubmitChanges()
            MsgBox("Data Successfully Updated!", MsgBoxStyle.Information + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Success!")
            Registration_Load(sender, e)
            txtClassTeacher.Text = ""
            txtClassName.Text = ""
            txtClassSName.Text = ""
            cboClassSection.Text = ""
        Else
            Registration_Load(sender, e)
            txtClassTeacher.Text = ""
            txtClassName.Text = ""
            txtClassSName.Text = ""
            cboClassSection.Text = ""
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Update not Successful!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "ALERT!!!")
        'Making(Adudjstiment)
        db.SubmitChanges()
    End Try
End Sub]
```

Thank you StackOverflow and MSDN for guidance